# My relationship is not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When i write this code my relationship is not working. How can i write this part of code so that i can access to `$article->translations()`. Any suggestion?

```
 $date_number = strval(date('m', strtotime($month)));
      $articles = DB::table('articles')->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) ='.$date_number)->where('approved',1)->get();

foreach($articles as $article){
    $article->trans = $article->translations()->whereHas('language',function($query) use($current_language_id){
      $query->where('id','=',$current_language_id);
    })->first();
  }
```

I got it. When i use   $articles = Articles::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) ='.$date_number)->where('approved',1)->get();

Comment: Not enough data is provided. Please show your relations and DB schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use query builder's `get` method it returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP `StdClass` object not an `Eloquent Model` object.

So you can't use the relations on `StdClass` object, you need an `Eloquent` object. And for that you should use `Eloquent` query builder as:

```
$articles = Article::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) ='.$date_number)
                ->where('approved',1)
                ->get();
```